# Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead

Tags: android, mvvmcross, toolbar

I'm having this issue when I applied the toolbar into my app and it crashed when I try to run the app.I used all previous post but no luck.
     Here is my code :

Style.xml

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>       

 </style>
```

I tried parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" but not worked.

Toolbar.xmal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />
```

Manifest.axml

```
    <application android:label="Capzure" android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your theme should look like this, and remove `@style/`:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then, do not define the theme in `<application/>` tag. Define it only with activity you want to use the material design theme, i.e. in `<activity>` tag.

If your activity extends `PreferenceActivity`, `AppCompatActivity`, or `ActionBarActivity`,  which you want to begin the transaction with `PreferenceFragment`, change your theme to:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

And remove this line from your Toolbar:

```
android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
```